# Elastalert deployment failed

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have installed elastalert on Centos 7.6 and while starting the elastalert receiving the following error.

```
[root@e2e-27-36 elastalert]# python -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --rule example_rules/example_frequency.yaml

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals

  File "/root/elastalert/elastalert/elastalert.py", line 29, in <module>
    from . import kibana

  File "elastalert/kibana.py", line 4, in <module>
    import urllib.error

ImportError: No module named error
```

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: https://python-forum.io/Thread-ImportError-No-module-named-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my fix by own.

1.On python2.7 the issue still persist

2.Install python3.6 version to fix the issue.

`yum install python3 python3-devel python3-urllib3`

3.Run the elastalert command

`python3 -m elastalert.elastalert --config /root/elastalert/config.yaml --verbose --rule /root/elastalert/example_rules/example_frequency.yaml`

4.If you received issue with the modules (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz')

5.Install the modules as per the requirement.

`pip3 install -r /root/elastalert/requirements.txt`

6.Let's run the command `"python3 -m elastalert.elastalert --config /root/elastalert/config.yaml --verbose --rule /root/elastalert/example_rules/example_frequency.yaml"` and got error

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='elasticsearch.example.com', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

7.Above error due to not valid hostname on config.yaml file. Edit the `config.yaml` file and change the hostname to server hostname at `es.hosts` field

Make sure you had an entry for the same on the `/etc/hosts` file.

8.Ok the issue got fixed and run the command `"python3 -m elastalert.elastalert --config /root/elastalert/config.yaml --verbose --rule /root/elastalert/example_rules/example_frequency.yaml"` and one more error

pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jira>=2.0.0'

9.We need to install the jira by using below command

`pip3 install jira==2.0.0`

10.Now let's run the command `"python3 -m elastalert.elastalert --config /root/elastalert/config.yaml --verbose --rule /root/elastalert/example_rules/example_frequency.yaml"` and again another error OMG.

elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(429, 'circuit_breaking_exception', '[parent] Data too large, data for [] would be [994793504/948.7mb], which is larger than the limit of [986061209/940.3mb], real usage: [994793056/948.7mb], new bytes reserved: [448/448b]')

11.You need to fix the same by changing the heap value on following `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`

`Xms-1g to Xms-2g
Xmx-1g to Xms-2g`
and restart elasticsearch service `"service elasticsearch restart"`

12.Everything set again run the command `"python3 -m elastalert.elastalert --config /root/elastalert/config.yaml --verbose --rule /root/elastalert/example_rules/example_frequency.yaml"` and ended up receiving another error.

ERROR:root:Error finding recent pending alerts: NotFoundError(404, 'index_not_found_exception', 'no such index [elastalert_status]', elastalert_status, index_or_alias) {'query': {'bool': {'must': {'query_string': {'query': '!*exists*:aggregate_id AND alert_sent:false'}}, 'filter': {'range': {'alert_time': {'from': '2019-12-04T19:45:09.635478Z', 'to': '2019-12-06T19:45:09.635529Z'}}}}}, 'sort': {'alert_time': {'order': 'asc'}}}

13.Fix the issue by running the below command

`elastalert-create-index`

14.Finally everything done and run the below command

`python3 -m elastalert.elastalert --config /root/elastalert/config.yaml --verbose --rule /root/elastalert/example_rules/example_frequency.yaml`

Now cancelled the command and ran the same on background

`python3 -m elastalert.elastalert --config /root/elastalert/config.yaml --verbose --rule /root/elastalert/example_rules/example_frequency.yaml &`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if urllib3 is installed by running `pip freeze` or try to reinstall it with `pip install urllib3`.

You maybe need to correctly activate your environment variable like this : `source [env]/bin/activate`.

Answer (score 0):

Setup conda environment

```
conda create -n elastalert python=3.6 anaconda
```

Activate conda env

```
conda activate elastalert
```

Install all the requirements

```
pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
```